# how to make dir only show the file information

Tags: batch-file, shell-script

I'm preparing a batch file doing some file copy, to show in the log if the source file exists, I'd like to add a line "dir sourcefile".

But how could I limit the result to only the file information?

Eg, below is the result

```
C:\Program Files\X Codec Pack>dir readme.txt
 Volume in drive C is Windows 7_x64
 Volume Serial Number is EEEE-FFFF

 Directory of C:\Program Files\X Codec Pack

03/06/2014  03:49 PM               835 Readme.txt
               1 File(s)            835 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  123,456,789,012 bytes free
```

However, I would only need 1 line in the log file:

```
03/06/2014  03:49 PM               835 Readme.txt
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do it is using "find", but offers not the best performance, probably.

```
dir readme.txt | find "readme.txt"
```

be aware of case sensitivity (use `find /I "readme.txt"` for insensitivity)